# <webview> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: electron

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at WebFrame.e.startsWith.e.startsWith.WebFrame.<computed> [as _executeJavaScript] (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:89)
    at electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:117
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:101)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315)
    at Object.onMessage (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:93)
```

On some computers, this error occurs in the Webview